# How often can we do a word by word translation from German to English?

Tags: difference, sentence-structure, german-to-english

I have a habit of doing a word by word translation when I encounter a new sentence structure. I have noticed a few patterns:

1. Sometimes there is a word for word match. e.g.,

   > Ich habe einen Kugelschreiber (German). I have a ballpoint pen (English).
2. Sometimes a few extra words are necessary in English. These are mostly verbs or prepositions. e.g.,

   > Haben Sie einen Kugelschreiber (German)? Do you have a ballpoint pen (English)?
3. Sometimes the order in which the words are arranged is different, although all words can be found. e.g.,

   > Ich gehe in meiner Pause joggen (German). I go jogging on my break (English).

How often can we do a word by word translation from German to English, i.e., category (1)?

Comment: How often? Per year?

Comment: @HalvarF No. Say in every 10 sentence, how many would have a word by word translation in English?

Comment: Probably a stupid question..  I know!

Comment: This question can't be answered without a representative corpus of sententences. Answers like "often" or "rarely" would be opinionated and off topic too.

Comment: @userunknown I am sorry. Should I delete the question?

Comment: I don't see, how to change it, into something which can be answered, so yes, but you might want to wait for more opinions on this.

Comment: I think you should do it as often as possible, just for the learning experience, as it can often be enlightening how a different language structures itself. That being said, this question is not really answerable.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the best way to answer this is to take a random paragraph in German and translate it word for word into English. You can then judge for yourself how well it works. Here's an example from the German version of the video game Stardew Valley, the opening scene. (In the scene, your grandfather is speaking to you from his deathbed.)

> ...and for my whole special grandson/granddaughter: I would like, that
> you this sealed envelope receive. No, no, open it yet not... have
> patience. Now, to-hear me...
> Of one day will you yourself perhaps in
> desperate sadness find...
> ...and your spirit will struggle, in order to
> awake stay. The day will come, at which you yourself the load of
> modern life pressed feel will...
> ...and your soul of the growing emptyness be conquered.
> When that happens, my boy/dear, will you ready for this gift be.
> Now let grandpa himself rest...

I don't think there's any line that wouldn't require at least a little rephrasing. Most are, at best, Yoda-esque. But the gist of the meaning is usually apparent.

Comment: Ob eine Wort-für-Wort-Übersetzung funktioniert hängt sehr von der Komplexität der Sätze ab, und damit indirekt vom Genre - wissenschaftliche Veröffentlichung, Roman, Kinderbuch, Zeitung (Boulevard?), gesprochene Sprache in verschiedenen Klassen. Dass ein Text aus einem Videospiel dafür repräsentativ ist wäre ein ziemlich unwahrscheinlicher Zufall. Das Layout des Zitats ist auch überarbeitungswürdig.

Comment: @user unknown: Yes, a lot depends on if you're talking about written or spoken language, formal or informal tone. There is no such thing as a representative paragraph. Without that you can't say much more than "not very often". I'm not sure it's a meaningful question as it stands. But, if a good answer isn't possible, perhaps this will do. The layout is pretty much as it appears in the game -- subtitles on the screen.

Comment: The underlaying question is a question about the grammatical similarity (with 100% similarity you can do a word-for-word translation). I don't see that this question is off-topic - but might be hard to answer. Maybe people with a background in natural language processing, and / or creating of translation services know these kind of statistics.

Answer (score 2):

In practice, almost never, unless you stay at a totally elementary "See Jane run" level.

All human languages follow the same fundamental principles, and closely related languages mirror each other in more of the details than less related languages. But all human languages also develop a certain level of ideosyncrasy. This level is surprisingly high, as is apparent whenever you actually try to write a grammar that encompasses *all* common language use. (It is also not just noise or decay; there is evidence e.g. that a certain level of spelling irregularity actually *helps* reading comprehension.)

These "bells and whistles" are largely arbitrary, as can be shown by cross-linguistic surveys, and in any realistic text they make it very unlikely that an entire sentence mirrors the structure of its translated counterpart in *every* detail.